# Retweet counts using Twitter REST API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to get ***retweet count for set of tweets***. With few search about it I found out that it could done using the **Twitter REST API (oauth)** , but it has limit with respect to number of request made (RATE LIMIT).Can anyone help me ***how to implement it using the oauth signature and without any limit.***

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently get retweet counts *without* obeying the limit:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting

Sorry.

You can always attempt to obey the limit and optimise your application/service. See the section in the above link titled "Tips to avoid being Rate Limited".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Christopher, yes i did read about the rate-limitings,but i have a constrain not to use other methods like Search or streaming API.I had an idea of using the oauth to get the Twitter data, but not sure of how to implement it .

Comment: link has expired